# Nginx Redirect Wordpress Post URL from "Post Name" to "Category Post Name"

Tags: nginx, redirect, wordpress, 301-redirect

How to make a 301 redirect using Nginx from the Wordpress URL "post name":

**example.com/best-movies-2020/**

to "category post name":

**example.com/movies/best-movies-2020/**

I'm a nginx starter. I have searched in Goolge but there is no exact solution that I found. I would really appreciate any help I can get on this.

Comment: Your question is too broad to offer an exact solution. There is probably a wordpress plug-in that does this, or you could use a `map` to create an exhaustive list of every URI that needs changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being I don't use Nginx redirects, I use this:

```
add_filter( '404_template', 'custom_redirect_to_category' );

function custom_redirect_to_category($template) {

    if ( ! is_404() ){
        return $template;
    }

    global $wp_rewrite;
    global $wp_query;

    if ( '/%category%/%postname%/' !== $wp_rewrite->permalink_structure ){
        return $template;
    }   

    if ( ! $post = get_page_by_path( $wp_query->query['category_name'], OBJECT, 'post' ) ){
        return $template;   
    }

    $permalink = get_permalink( $post->ID );

    wp_redirect( $permalink, 301 );
    exit;

}
```